# に particle with 乾く and 響く

Tags: grammar, parsing, relative-clauses, coordination

I'm playing a visual novel and there is the following sentence:

> 時折響く、司会者のバカみたいにカン高い笑い声。
>
> 真っ白くて日当たりの良いこの部屋に、乾き、響いていた。

The 乾き here is confusing. I know it might be related to 日当たりの良い部屋, but either the comma is separating an unusual compound verb like "乾き響く" or it's separating the verb stem continuative forms, as in "...この部屋に乾き、響いていた". If it's the latter case, what exactly the に particle tells with the verb 乾く? Usually, the は or が particle is used to indicate what is dry. There is another remote possibility that the word 乾き here is being used as a noun (dryness), but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first sentence is a big noun phrase with 笑い声 as its head. The second sentence can be understood as taking the previous head as its implicit subject, making it a coordination of 笑い声が乾いている and 笑い声が響いている.

XがYに響く means the sound (X) fills/touches Y.
XがYに乾く does not seem idiomatic, so Y would be just the place the event is taking place.

乾いて響く is a more common collocation meaning "something rings dry" or "something makes a dry echoing sound". So it might be a bit of a word play slightly deviating from that.